# Add-DnsServerResourceRecord with multiple lines of descriptive text

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm trying to add multiple strings to the `-DescriptiveText` property of a single resource record using the command as shown in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecord?view=windowsserver2019-ps#example-8--add-a-multiline-txt-resource-record):

```
# a,b,c,d in the following are different items separated by `r`n
Add-DNSServerResourceRecord -DescriptiveText "a`r`nb`r`nc`r`nd" -Name "identifier" -Txt -ZoneName $ZONE -ZoneScope $ZONE_SCOPE -TimeToLive 0:1:0:0
```

I know the expected return value of another command that retrieves this data results in the following:

```
TXT
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"
    "d"
```

However the above returns the following which doesn't work

```
TXT
    "a
b
c
d"
```

I have tried other methods as follows including:

- Trying arrays like `"a","b","c","d"` as referenced in the accepted answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d85a48d-09ca-4d7d-b531-0c5c59745bd0/powershell-3-add-multistring-txt-record-to-dns?forum=winserverpowershell) which errored
- Other methods of formatting the string to match the expected output involving adding missing quotes marks to try and align it with the expected return value
- Tried calling the command with each individual part which made multiple records with the required data but didn't work as it needs to be in one record

Any advice on how to do it would be appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried escaping the double quotes?
"`"a`"`r`n`"b`"`r`n`"c`"`r`n`"d`""

Comment: @DavidMartin Yep, tried that.

Comment: "However the above returns the following which doesn't work" What doesn't work? You have to separate how `TXT` records are typically stored in zonefiles and transmitted on the wire, from how they are used by applications. Per DNS specifications a `TXT` record is one or more strings of up to 255 bytes. Which is why it can show as `"a" "b" "c"` etc... But the application consuming the data does not see this split, it would see a value of `abc` for the example (everything concatenated as is). Don't confuse that with having multiple separate `TXT` records, even on the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Txt records can have multiple strings and/or multiline strings. It looks like your other command is expecting the former.

Unfortunately, the `Add-DnsServerResourceRecord` cmdlet only accepts a single string for the `DescriptiveText`.  `` `r`n `` only adds a newline to that single string, which is why your tool isn't processing them as separate entries.

Instead, use `dnscmd`:

```
dnscmd.exe servername /recordadd example.com identifier TXT "a" "b" "c"
```

A similar annoyance is that `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` will only return the first string of a text record as well.